# Random 404 when using flask test client to test EVE API server

Tags: python, flask, pytest, eve

I have an API server build using EVE framework.
I am using py.test framework for testing. I came across a weird problem.

If I test my APIs using flask's `test_client` I get unpredictable results. i.e. If I run `py.test` command 3 times in a row, back to back (without any changes to tests) from the terminal, I get different results e.g.

```
3 passed, 5 failed 
5 passed, 3 failed
8 passed, 0 failed
```

The tests that fail with `404` for the URL (resource endpoint)

If I use `requests` library instead of the `test_client`, everything works correctly, i.e. `8 passed` every time I run the tests.

I have a code similar to the following :

```
client = app.test_client()

# POST_METHOD = client.post
# BASE_URL = '/'
# GET_METHOD = client.get

POST_METHOD = requests.post
BASE_URL = 'http://' + app.config.get('SERVER_NAME') + '/'
GET_METHOD = requests.get
...
...
...
url = BASE_URL + 'resource1'
...
...
r = POST_METHOD(url, data=json.dumps(somedata), headers=headers)
```

I can consistently reproduce this problem, by simply switching the commented and uncommented code from the top 3 lines, and using `test_client` instead of `requests`

I had initially thought that this is something to do with timing (`test_client` tests running faster than `requests`) But `404` is baffling.
Why would an endpoint **vanish** ?

--

[this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1454#issuecomment-137383748) may be related, but the token is not part of my URL. It is part of the header.

Comment: is the behaviour the same when you use `with app.test_client() as client: client.post(...)`?

Comment: @Peter I haven't tried. Will let you know.

Comment: @mandar i am facing the same issue , by any chance is you network behind a proxy server

Comment: @hemraj No, not behind a proxy. But it shouldn't matter. this is all local testing. Both the server and test client are on my laptop.